# Show $f$ is of bounded variation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, bounded-variation

Suppose f is a continuous function on $[0,1]$, f' exists on all $(0,1)$ and f' is monotonically increasing on $(0,1)$. Do not assume $f'$ is bounded. **Show** $f$ is of bounded variation on $[0,1]$.

Need to show that for all partitions $P$ on $[0,1]$ the sum given by $\sum_{P} |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})|$ is bounded by some number independent of the partition chosen - or alternatively - that the supremum of such sums over all partitions is bounded.

Things we know:

~By the Mean Value Theorem, we can find a $c_k \in (x_{k-1},x_k)$ for all $k$ such that $f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1}) = f'(c_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})$. Then we have $|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| = |f'(c_k)|*|(x_k-x_{k-1})|$. We don't know that f' is bounded though...

~We also know that f is continuous which means $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(y)| < \epsilon$. If $P$ is a partition where the lengths of the subintervals are less than $\delta$, then for all $k$, we have $|x_k-x_{k-1}|$ and therefore $|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| < \epsilon$.

~$f'$ is strictly increasing which says $y > x \Rightarrow f'(y) > f'(x)$.

How do I get that $f$ is of bounded variation?

Comment: From M.V.T and Continuity definition we get $|f^{'}(c_{k})| < \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}$

Comment: So $\sum_{P} |f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})| < \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}*\sum_{P} |x_k-x_{k-1}| = \frac{\epsilon}{\delta}*(1-0)$?

Comment: My comment was not correct. Sorry.

Comment: $f$ isn't known to be increasing, the derivative of $f$ is. Otherwise the problem would be trivial.

Comment: May be you have to use the fact that the derivative changes its sign at most one time.

Comment: Then if $f'$ is positive on [0,1] or $f'$ is negative on (0,1) everything is OK. Otherwise you will split the interval into two sub intervals by the point where $f'$ changes its sign.

Answer (score 3):

Since $f'$ is increasing, we have that it changes sign at most once. If $f$ is strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, the problem is trivial, so assume $f'$ has a zero at $x_0$. Then the variation is $f(0)-f(x_0)+f(1)-f(x_0)=f(0)+f(1)-2f(x_0)$.

The idea is just splitting the interval into pieces where $f$ is monotonic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very obvious to me now that I see it. The textbook also noted that the same conclusion holds even if $f'$ is not strictly increasing. Could the same reasoning still be applied even if $f'$ is not monotonic? Then you'd potentially have a lot of "pieces" where f is monotonic.

Comment: @antsatsui: As long as it is a finite number of times, it will work exactly the same :)